# Can I become a reserve fighter plane pilot in the Indian air force?

Tags: pilots, indian-air-force, india

I am a B.Tech Computer Science student in India. Soon after my studies I will get a job somewhere in computer science field. I am interested in technology, and things like Artificial Intelligence that is why I joined this technological field. **But,** I have huge interests in flying aircraft and also some other fields. When I was young, I wanted to be a pilot.

**We have reserve army in India, so do we have reserve air force also?**

**If yes, how can I become reserve fighter pilot in it?**

**What is the procedure for it?**

In this way my two other dreams will also fulfill that are flying and
serving nation in part of the year.

So as a conclusion, in major part of year I want to work in technology (AI in computer science) and in remaining part of year, I want to serve the nation as reserve fighter pilot.

Comment: While there may be members of the IAF that post here, you would be best served speaking with a recruiter.  I am a former US military pilot, but I would give the same advice to a US citizen because while some requirements are constant, others change based on current staffing levels.

Comment: I'm not sure how it works in India, but in the US this would be difficult to do. Most USAFR pilots are ex-military, in order to become a pilot you would need to be a commissioned officer and complete OCS, as well as the pilot training. As far as I can tell, India does not have a reserve air force.

Comment: @RonBeyer, Bro people asked me to ask this separately, that's why I asked here, also I did not get its answer in previous question and i also deleted my previous question because that was not well framed. So i do not think that this is duplicate.

Comment: @RonBeyer, so is there something like this reserve air force in usa?

Comment: @MichaelHall, so is there something like this reserve air force in usa?

Comment: Yes, the USA has reserve forces, but as Ron mentioned, pilots generally do a significant stint on active duty before going reserve.

Comment: And while the US does allow foreigners to join its military and earn citizenship, that requires years of active duty and the odds of getting selected as a fighter pilot is ... not good.